# How to open more than one folder at a time in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gui

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed in my Thinkpad T440 but I came along with a problem that is I just can open one folder at a time in GUI mode. 
I saw others answers saying to middle click or right click with shift pressed or without but I can't get this done in both ways because I can't use (or I don't have I don't know) a middle clicking device or my touchpad is misconfigured or not working properly.

How would I solve this problem?
I am using Gnome Flashback

Comment: I don't really understand what you can't do. Nautilus used to have `F3` for a dual-pane display, but although that is not present in current versions you can have as many Nautilus windows open as you want. `PCManFM` and `Nemo File Manager` still have the `F3` dual-pane option.

Comment: I don't know either. In my other notebook, that runs Ubuntu 14.10 it runs perfectly but on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS don't.

Comment: You still haven't explained what you can't do. Do you not know how to open more than one copy of Nautilus? Do you not know how to install one of the alternative file managers? Can you not use Faizan's answer?

Comment: @AFH I tried Faizan answer but did not work. I use Nautilus with Ubuntu 14.10 and I can open many instances of same folder I want without a problem. Oh Ubuntu 14.04 using gnome fallback not.

Comment: So what happens when you open a new instance? You can use `Alt-F2`, or the `Places` or `Applications` menu (Accessories->Files), if you get these in Gnome Fall-back (I got them in Gnome Classic), or you can type `nautilus&` in a terminal. It all worked for me in 14.04, though many other things didn't, and I have since upgraded to 14.10, so I can't do detailed investigations for you.

Answer (score 0):

Shift + Double Click or Right Click on any folder and choose Open in New Tab